# How do I get Django to display integers instead of floats

Tags: python, django, function, truncate

I am working with Django and I have a project where I define a Student object that has the fields of grade 1 and grade 2 of type FLOAT, in this class, I build a function that gives back the grade of the student in question although I encountered a problem, the useless digit when I've got an integer number. For example, if your grade is 5 and 9 you get 7.0 and I want to know how can I make the HTML/Django logic syntax display what it should. Just in case it is needed this is the function of how I calculate the grade.

```
    def get_grade(self):

        if self.grade_1 is None and self.grade_2 is None:
            return "No grades yet"
        elif self.grade_2 is None:
            return self.grade_1
        elif self.grade_1 is None:
            return self.grade_2
        else:
            return (self.grade_1 + self.grade_2)/2
```

Comment: Your question looks much more like "How do I get Django to display integers without decimal part and floats with one digit after the decimal point" - so this piece of code is irrelevant, and you should make your question more about your real problem.

Comment: Main problem is to know when a float is meant to be an integer (instead of being only near an integer value). If you do multiple calculations you may have to keep track of this somehow.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you, kind stranger, I edited the question to sound more like my problem

Comment: `return (self.grade_1 + self.grade_2) // 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the sum of grade 1 and grade2 will result in float when divided by 2.This can be checked by calculating modulus. If the modulus returns 0, it means result will have 0 in decimal part.
If modulus is 0, return result converted to integer which will remove the decimal part, else return the result as float itself.
Example:

- 3.0 % 2 == 1.0 and thus return result 3.0 / 2 = 1.5
- 2.0 % 2 == 0.0 and thus return result (int)(2.0 / 2) == 1

Make changes in the else block as follows:

```
total = self.grade_1 + self.grade_2
if total%2 == 0:
    return (int)(result/2)
else:
    return result2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want integer values then you can use round or int while returning the values..
something like below

```
def get_grade(self):

    if self.grade_1 is None and self.grade_2 is None:
        return "No grades yet"
    elif self.grade_2 is None:
        return int(self.grade_1)
    elif self.grade_1 is None:
        return int(self.grade_2)
    else:
        return int((self.grade_1 + self.grade_2)/2)
```

or round() as below

```
def get_grade(self):

    if self.grade_1 is None and self.grade_2 is None:
        return "No grades yet"
    elif self.grade_2 is None:
        return round(self.grade_1)
    elif self.grade_1 is None:
        return round(self.grade_2)
    else:
        return round((self.grade_1 + self.grade_2)/2)
```

Comment: It would work just fine if it would have been what I wanted, to get rid of those decimals that are not needed, not all of them